# Is it safe to convert json to jsonb?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, logical-replication

I have a problem with logical replication `could not identify an equality operator for type json`. I found a solution where they say to replace json fields with jsonb to solve this problem. I checked json and jsonb operators, and saw that jsonb doesn't have any operators that json doesn't have. I mean, if jsonb extends the capabilities of json, then would it be safe to make an alert and have the field type from json to jsonb?

Logs on replica:

> LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for
> subscription "mysub", table "order_f" has started

> ERROR:  could not
> identify an equality operator for type json

> background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 45) exited with exit code 1

primary instance version - PostgreSQL 14.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit (on AWS RDS)

replica instance version - PostgreSQL 14.4 (Debian 14.4-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit (self hosted in docker)

[table DDL](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ocO6dVs)

Comment: van you post a dbfiddle, with the problem query and of course with data

Comment: problem not in query. `could not identify an equality operator for type json` - it is error log on replica

Comment: Safe for what purpose exactly? You might rather want to cast it to `text` for comparison if you need to handle differently formatted json documents separately. If you do not care about whitespaces, object property order, and duplicate properties, casting to `jsonb` should be fine - but even better, change the column type that stores the `json` in the first place.

Comment: I think you would be better served by identifying what caused the problem in the first place. To that end add more information to your question:  1) Postgres versions involved. 2) Direction of replication. 3) The replication statements being used. 4) The complete error message. **Add this as text **.

Comment: What is the table definition(including indexes) for `order_f`?

Comment: Order us a reserved word in SQL and PostgreSQL, use a better name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is safe, yon can directly convert it.

```
CREATE tABLE t (j json)
```

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN j TYPE jsonb USING j::jsonb;
```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NXsC34fT)